# Need help about generating a number in Crystal report

Tags: vb.net

Need help about generating a number in Crystal report

for example :

last record entered = 1009

next record should be 1010, 1011, 1012

how to do something like this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific, perhaps post the code you have got to date, and what part of the code isn't working? You'll get more help that way.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat unclear to me, and here's is my best guess of what you are looking for:

> Assuming you are showing every row in the DETAIL section, then you
>   want to drag the RECORD NUMBER in from the SPECIAL FIELDS section into
>   you detail row on the report design.

[From here](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=679595). This solution worked for OP.

You may also be looking to have an [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column in the database, which automatically increments itself with new records. You can select this column in your query, even though such approach is rarely used.